# How to assign value to a c++ string index by index

Tags: c++, string

How to assign value to a c++ string index by index. I have tried this code but this is not changing the value of the string.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string>

void change(string & str)
{
    str[0] = '1';
    str[1] = '2';
    // str = "12" ; // it works but i want to assign value to each index separately. 
}
void main()
{
    string str;
    change(str);
    cout << str << endl; // expected "12"
}
```

Comment: _"How to assign value to a c++ string index by index"_ Easy : `str[0] = '1'; str[1] = '2';` However, you must make sure that `str[1]` exist before that.

Comment: What do you get instead of expected "12"? Also, keep in mind that `string` should know not only content of each element but also size. I suspect you are getting empty string printed because (despite the fact [0]th and [1]st elements are assigned) its size is still 0.

Comment: You should `#include <iostream>` instead of `iostream.h`, and that code doesn't compile because you're not prefixing `string`, `cout`, and `endl` with `std::`. Also `main()` should return `int`, not `void`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this, but before you can assign characters by index, you have to first resize the string such that those indices are valid.

```
str.resize(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this code does not even compile.
Errors:

1. `<iostream.h>` is not a standard header. Use just `<header>`.
2. Use `using namespace std;` or prefix `cout` and `endl`with `std::`.
3. `main` must return `int`, not `void`.

Then the size of the string is still zero, so it's an undefined behaviour to change `str[0]` and `str[1]`.

To fix it, set its dimension using `std::string::resize (size_t)`:

```
str.resize (2);
```

Comment: `<string>` is needed, even though other headers define `std::string`. Some implementation (like MSVC) don't define _everything_ of `std::string` in other headers (like the `ostream` overloads), so it is better to include it, to make it platform/compiler independent.

Comment: Thanks and btw it does compile on windows's compiler (c-free). so didn't notice the syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Using the STL `sstream` for `stringstreams` makes it much easier for appending and creating dynamic strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void change(stringstream *ss, char value) {
    *ss << value;
}

int main() {
    stringstream stream;
    stream << "test";

    change(&stream, 't');

    cout << stream.str() << endl; //Outputs 'testt'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: appending is not the same as chaning the value at a certain index